# Where I can download msiexec.exe for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I try to run an `.msi` file I get a Windows dialog box prompting me to select an app to open the `.msi` file.

I think that I accidentally deleted `msiexec.exe`, the Windows Installer executable that runs `.msi` files on Windows 10.

Where I can download it again?

Comment: I am not sure of the file name I deleted but this is the file that make .msi can run on windows.

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem?  *What* are you trying to do, what you are doing it *with*, and what type of *error message* do you receive.

Comment: the msi files are no longer run. when I try to run msi file I get windows dialog prompt me to select an app to open msi file. msi files should be executed like exe and the file that run this extension was deleted

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something modified your Windows 10 configuration to change the default `.msi` file type association.  As a result, they won't execute properly.

Utilize the following code by pasting it into Notepad, saving it as a `.reg` file and merging it with admin privileges to restore your default file type association. You can also download the same code within a readily available `.reg` file from original source referenced below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.tenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a.html


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.msi]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.msi]
@="Msi.Package"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package]
@="Windows Installer Package"
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,10,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,6d,00,73,00,69,00,6d,00,73,00,67,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,\
  00,2d,00,33,00,34,00,00,00
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.Title;System.Subject;System.Category;System.Keywords;System.Comment;System.PropGroup.Origin;System.Author;System.Document.RevisionNumber;System.Document.DateCreated;System.ApplicationName;System.PropGroup.FileSystem;System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemType;System.ItemFolderPathDisplay;System.DateCreated;System.DateModified;System.Size;System.FileAttributes;System.OfflineAvailability;System.OfflineStatus;System.SharedWith;System.FileOwner;System.ComputerName"
"InfoTip"="prop:System.ItemType;System.Author;System.Title;System.Subject;System.Comment;System.DateModified;System.Size"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\msiexec.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell]
@="Open,Repair,Uninstall"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Open]
@="&Install"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6d,00,73,00,69,00,6d,00,73,00,67,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  33,00,36,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,00,\
  73,00,69,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,63,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,\
  00,69,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Repair]
@="Re&pair"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6d,00,73,00,69,00,6d,00,73,00,67,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  33,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Repair\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,00,\
  73,00,69,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,63,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,\
  00,66,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Uninstall]
@="&Uninstall"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6d,00,73,00,69,00,6d,00,73,00,67,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  33,00,38,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\Uninstall\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,00,\
  73,00,69,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,63,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,\
  00,78,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.msi]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.msi]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.msi]
```

(Source:  [Restore Default File Type Associations in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html))

If the problem still persists, open an elevated command prompt and run `sfc /scannow` in an attempt to repair your operating system.

Comment: No I think I deleted msiexec.exe. this reg wont help me

Comment: If that's the case, try running [sfc /scannow](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) in an attempt to repair your system.  And once it's done, I would *still* run the `.reg` file.